# When executing SOAP request in SOAP UI, I get this below error

Tags: web-services, jboss, soapui

I get this below error when I execute SOAP request in SOAP UI , for the webservice developed.

```
2015.09.08 08:02:59:920 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:DEBUG com.wipro.security.cid.CIDLookupDelegateException in Lookup:com.wipro.security.exception.WSSecurityException : Please contact system administrator
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
2015.09.08 08:02:59:920 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR Exception in CIDLookupService
2015.09.08 08:02:59:921 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR class com.wipro.security.exception.WSSecurityException
2015.09.08 08:02:59:922 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR Exception --->Internal Service Error
2015.09.08 08:02:59:923 Env/activeThread-5:INFO:STDOUT Analysis to get CID response:: <CIDLOOKUP_RESPONSE:CIDLOOKUP_RESPONSE xmlns:CIDLOOKUP_RESPONSE="http://websecure.wipro.com"><CIDLOOKUP_RESPONSE:CID></CIDLOOKUP_RESPONSE:CID><CIDLOOKUP_RESPONSE:ERROR><CIDLOOKUP_RESPONSE:ERROR_CODE>1001</CIDLOOKUP_RESPONSE:ERROR_CODE><CIDLOOKUP_RESPONSE:ERROR_MESSAGE>Internal Service Error</CIDLOOKUP_RESPONSE:ERROR_MESSAGE></CIDLOOKUP_RESPONSE:ERROR></CIDLOOKUP_RESPONSE:CIDLOOKUP_RESPONSE>
2015.09.08 08:02:59:923 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR com.wipro.security.exception.WSSecurityException : Please contact system administrator
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
2015.09.08 08:02:59:923 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR         at com.wipro.security.cid.ejb.CIDLookupManagerBean.CIDLookup(CIDLookupManagerBean.java:102)
2015.09.08 08:02:59:923 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2015.09.08 08:02:59:923 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
2015.09.08 08:02:59:923 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
2015.09.08 08:02:59:923 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
2015.09.08 08:02:59:923 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR         at org.jboss.invocation.Invocation.performCall(Invocation.java:359)
2015.09.08 08:02:59:923 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR         at org.jboss.ejb.StatelessSessionContainer$ContainerInterceptor.invoke(StatelessSessionContainer.java:237)
2015.09.08 08:02:59:924 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR         at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionInterceptor.invoke(CachedConnectionInterceptor.java:158)
2015.09.08 08:02:59:924 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR         at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.StatelessSessionInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessSessionInstanceInterceptor.java:169)
2015.09.08 08:02:59:924 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR         at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.CallValidationInterceptor.invoke(CallValidationInterceptor.java:63)
2015.09.08 08:02:59:924 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR         at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.AbstractTxInterceptor.invokeNext(AbstractTxInterceptor.java:121)
2015.09.08 08:02:59:924 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR         at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.TxInterceptorCMT.runWithTransactions(TxInterceptorCMT.java:350)
2015.09.08 08:02:59:924 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR         at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.TxInterceptorCMT.invoke(TxInterceptorCMT.java:181)
2015.09.08 08:02:59:924 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR         at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.SecurityInterceptor.invoke(SecurityInterceptor.java:168)
2015.09.08 08:02:59:924 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR         at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.LogInterceptor.invoke(LogInterceptor.java:205)
2015.09.08 08:02:59:924 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR         at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.ProxyFactoryFinderInterceptor.invoke(ProxyFactoryFinderInterceptor.java:138)
2015.09.08 08:02:59:924 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR         at org.jboss.ejb.SessionContainer.internalInvoke(SessionContainer.java:648)
2015.09.08 08:02:59:924 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR         at org.jboss.ejb.Container.invoke(Container.java:960)
2015.09.08 08:02:59:924 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2015.09.08 08:02:59:924 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
2015.09.08 08:02:59:924 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
2015.09.08 08:02:59:924 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
2015.09.08 08:02:59:924 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR         at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
2015.09.08 08:02:59:924 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR         at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
2015.09.08 08:02:59:924 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR         at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
2015.09.08 08:02:59:924 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR         at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
2015.09.08 08:02:59:925 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR         at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
2015.09.08 08:02:59:925 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR         at org.jboss.invocation.local.LocalInvoker$MBeanServerAction.invoke(LocalInvoker.java:169)
2015.09.08 08:02:59:925 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR         at org.jboss.invocation.local.LocalInvoker.invoke(LocalInvoker.java:118)
2015.09.08 08:02:59:925 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR         at org.jboss.invocation.InvokerInterceptor.invokeLocalMarshalled(InvokerInterceptor.java:295)
2015.09.08 08:02:59:925 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR         at org.jboss.invocation.MarshallingInvokerInterceptor.invoke(MarshallingInvokerInterceptor.java:61)
2015.09.08 08:02:59:925 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR         at org.jboss.proxy.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:61)
2015.09.08 08:02:59:925 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR         at org.jboss.proxy.SecurityInterceptor.invoke(SecurityInterceptor.java:70)
2015.09.08 08:02:59:925 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR         at org.jboss.proxy.ejb.StatelessSessionInterceptor.invoke(StatelessSessionInterceptor.java:112)
2015.09.08 08:02:59:925 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR         at org.jboss.proxy.ClientContainer.invoke(ClientContainer.java:100)
2015.09.08 08:02:59:925 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR         at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy191.CIDLookup(Unknown Source)
2015.09.08 08:02:59:925 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR         at com.wipro.security.cid.CIDLookupDelegate.CIDLookup(CIDLookupDelegate.java:100)
2015.09.08 08:02:59:925 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR         at com.wipro.websecure.we.CIDLookupService.CIDLookupService(CIDLookupService.java:253)
2015.09.08 08:02:59:925 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2015.09.08 08:02:59:925 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
2015.09.08 08:02:59:925 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
2015.09.08 08:02:59:925 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
2015.09.08 08:02:59:925 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR         at org.apache.axis2.receivers.RawXMLINOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RawXMLINOutMessageReceiver.java:97)
2015.09.08 08:02:59:925 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR         at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.java:42)
2015.09.08 08:02:59:926 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR         at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:100)
2015.09.08 08:02:59:926 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR         at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:176)
2015.09.08 08:02:59:926 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR         at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:275)
2015.09.08 08:02:59:926 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR         at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:133)
2015.09.08 08:02:59:926 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
2015.09.08 08:02:59:926 Env/activeThread-5:ERROR:STDERR         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
```

Coding is carried in Client box, I get this error only in dev box , not in QA(testing)box. I googled and got lots of solutions, but none worked for me.

We use JBOSS .

can anyone let me know what is the actual problem here?

Comment: You need to include more of the stacktrace and more of your code if you want us to help you. But reading what you provided, it is clear that the trustAnchors parameter has to not be empty.

Comment: I have modified the questions, i have added more of stack trace, unfortunately I couldn't share the client code here.

Comment: Well, despite that, the error is the "trustAnchors" parameter which is required is not present, as evidenced by the first line of the stacktrace.

Comment: exactly. thts what i am asking here for the help to let me know what is exactly missing in JBOSS for this.

Comment: You can use a product like SoapUI to construct your call to the server and test it. Obviously it is a problem with the SOAP request which misses a parameter. http://www.soapui.org/

Comment: You are most likely missing the the proper turststore entry in your JVM arguments of the JBoss startup.

Comment: @baba: the SOPA request works good in test environment. the problem is only with dev environment. So i dont thk its SOPA request missing some parameter.

Comment: @CoolBeans: Can you please eloborate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I resolved this error. I updated certs in security folder in JDK `/jdk1.6.0_41_new/jre/lib/security` , then it worked fine.

Thank you for all the above answers and comments.

Answer (score 0):

The error Message means that the trust store can not be found or that there is a Security problem stopping you accessing it.

Since it is working on the QA machine and not in Dev, you need to check what is installed and / or configured differently With respect to the trust store on the 2 machines.